# trying to understand my problems in my code

Tags: c, visual-studio, helper

Input data works for me in the Init function. But once I put in some names and ask for the score of an existing name or a non-existent name, it always returns the grade of the first name

I create two arrays. One of names and one of grade.
Checks whether they meet all the terms of "proper name" as defined by us.
Takes another name and checks if it is in a database. If so, returns the score if it does not return -1

```
''''
int Data_duplication(char* temp, char** names, int line);
void Init(char*** names, int** grades, int* size);
int Find(char** names, int* grades, int size, char* name);
void FreeAll(char*** names, int** grades, int size);
int main()
{
    char** Names = NULL;
    int* Grades = NULL;
    int size,grade;
    char name[SIZE] = { 0 };
    Init(&Names, &Grades, &size);
    printf("Enter a student name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    grade=Find(Names, Grades, size, name);
    printf("%d", grade);
    FreeAll(&Names, &Grades, size);
    return 0;

}
void Init(char*** names, int** grades, int* size)
{
    int i, j, flag;
    int strlengh;
    char temp[SIZE] = { 0 };
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    scanf("%d", size);
    *names = (char**)malloc((*size) * sizeof(char*));
    if (!(*names))
    {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    *grades = (int*)malloc((*size) * sizeof(int));
    if (!*grades)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0;i < *size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a name\n");
        scanf("%s", temp);
        strlengh = strlen(temp);
        do
        {
            flag = 1;
            if (strlen(temp) > 20)//if it longer then it should be
                flag = 0;
            if (temp[0] > 'Z' || temp[0] < 'A') //start with capital letter
                flag = 0;
            for (j = 1;temp[j] != '\0';j++)//all the letter is a lower case letters except from the first
            {
                if (temp[j] > 'z' || temp[j] < 'a')
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (Data_duplication(temp, *names, i))//if its not a name that already entered
            {
                flag = 0;
            }
            if (flag)//if the name is ok
            {
                (*names)[i] = (char*)malloc((strlengh + 1) * sizeof(char));
                if (!(*names)[i])
                {
                    printf("Error");
                    return;
                }
                strcpy((*names)[i], temp);
            }
            else//if somthing wrong
            {
                printf("Bad name,try again.\n");
                scanf("%s",temp);
            }
        } while (!flag);

        printf("Enter grade\n");
        scanf("%d", (*grades + i));
        while ( *(*grades + i) < 0 || *(*grades + i) > 100)//if the grade between 0 to 100
        {
            printf("Bad grade,try again.\n");
            scanf("%d", (*grades + i));
        }
    }

}
int Data_duplication(char* temp, char** names, int line)//find if there is another name like this that already entered
{
    for (int i = 0;i < line;i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(temp, names[i]))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int Find(char** names, int* grades, int size, char* name)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i < size;i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name,names[i])==0);
        {
            return (*(grades+i));
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
void FreeAll(char*** names, int** grades, int size)//free al the dynamic memo allocation
{
    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        free(*(*names + i));
    }
    free(*names);
    free(*grades);

}
```

[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Seeing `char***` as an argument type is not a great sign. That's a lot of pointer indirection!

Comment: That's what we were asked to do. What should I fix?
Did you see the problem I was talking about?

Comment: Is the expected output 50?

Comment: Yes, it should be 50

Comment: Oh, it's one of *those* courses. Do what you can to survive it but remember that in production code you don't want to get too deep with those pointers. You'll often lose track of what's going on, or will waste lots of CPU time resolving pointers. Step through in a debugger to see what's going on. Hard to tell just by looking at your code.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `*(*names + i)` use the array notation: `*names[i]` for much simpler code.

Comment: i'll try,thank you :)

Comment: Hint: You can edit your question to include the output as text and remove the graphics.

Comment: i found the problam...a rookie mistake...in the "Find" function i put ; after the if...the program works. Anyway, thanks for the help :)